# How can I make these \parbox margins wider in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, positioning, margins, parbox, textwidth

I have the below command, followed by the text that I want displayed. I've attached a display of the output. I would like the top middle text to have wider margins. I've tried tweaking the \parbox command with \textwidth but have not achieved the result that I want.

```
\newcommand\rexbox[1]{%
      \parbox{.333\textwidth}{#1}%
    }

\noindent\rexbox{\small City, State}\rexbox{\small This is the text that I want to be on multiple lines but would like the horiz. margins wider}\rexbox{\hfill \small Oct 2018}\\
\noindent City, State \hfill This is text that is fine on one line \hfill Oct 2018\\
```

[image]

Comment: You fixed the size of the `parbox` in your `rexbox` definition to be `.333` of `\texwidth`. So, unless you change that, that's what you'll get. How about: `\parbox{.25\textwidth}{\small City, State}\parbox{.5\textwidth}{\small This is the text that I want to be on multiple lines but would like the horiz. margins wider}\parbox{.25\textwidth}{\hfill \small Oct 2018}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set this in a [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) (if you're not concerned about content requiring a break across the page boundary:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{} l X r @{} }
  City, State &
    This is the text that I want to be on multiple lines but would like the horiz. margins wider &
    Oct 2018 \\
  City, State &
    This is text that is fine on one line &
    Oct 2018
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

The width of the `X`-column will stretch to fill whatever remains of `\linewidth` after the other (`l`eft - and `r`ight-aligned) columns have been set.

Comment: What is the meaning of the `@` variable?

Comment: @ron: It forms part of the column specification and denotes any inter-column specification. `@{}` removes the spacing between adjacent columns. Using `@{\hspace{4em}}` would insert a `4em` column space, for example.